# Trying to get property 'department' of non-object

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i having this error ****Trying to get property 'department' of non-object**** i want to display eloquent relationship 
i have error on this line

```
@foreach($posts as $announces)
        @foreach ($announces->posts as $post)




                <div class="card col-md-3 offset-3"  style="width: 18rem; margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 30px;">
                <h5 class="card-header">{{ $post->departments->department }}->{{ $post->Title }}</h5>
                <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="card-text">{{ $post->Content}}</p>

                        </div>
                </div> 

         @endforeach

    @endforeach
```

and this is my controller

```
public function index()
    {
        $posts = Department::all();
        return view('superadminpage.admin_update',compact('posts'));
    }
```

Comment: Could you plz add your models ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the structure of your Department model is but you probably don't want nested for-loops. Assuming Department has properties 'department' and 'title':

```
@foreach($departments as $department)
  <h5 class="card-header">{{ $department->department }} {{ $department->title }}</h5>
@endforeach
```

Your controller:

```
public function index()
{
     $departments = Department::all();
     return view('superadminpage.admin_update',compact('departments'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically your `$post->departments` variable is a collection [] which mean you need to loop through it